# Implementation of 32-bit floats or 64-bit longs in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, floating-point, long-integer, ieee-754

Does anyone know of a JavaScript library that accurately implements the [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) specification for 32-bit floating-point values?  I'm asking because I'm trying to write a cross-compiler in JavaScript, and since the source language has strict requirements that floating-point values adhere to IEEE 754, the generated JavaScript code must do so as well.  This means that I must be able to get exactly the correct IEEE 754 values for addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division of 32-bit floats.  Unfortunately, the standard JavaScript Number type is a 64-bit double, which will give different results than what I'm expecting.  The project really does have to be in JavaScript, and this is the only major stumbling block I have yet to get past.

I'm also running into this problem with 64-bit longs.

Comment: You're making a what?!? (impressed) A compiler for what, exactly?

Comment: @amphetamachine- If all goes well (crosses fingers!) an implementation of the JVM that runs in JavaScript.  It's for teaching intro CS online.  I didn't expect this to be the bottleneck - I figured out how to do threading and everything before this stumped me. :-)

Comment: I'm guessing you've already invested a lot of effort into this, so I think it might actually be worth attempting the implementation yourself.

The details are left as an exercise for the reader. :)

Comment: One trick that might help: using a bitwise operator can force the interpreter to treat a number as a 32-bit signed integer, instead of a 64-bit floating point. (number|0) is particularly useful, as it doesn't affect the number but forces it to be treated as an integer value.

Comment: I do find it pretty ridiculous that Javascript *enshrines* IEEE-754's binary64 in its language specification (see ECMA-262 §8.5), but that's neither here nor there…

Comment: I found your question while looking for the same thing for the same reason, see https://github.com/ghewgill/lentil. We should collaborate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Closure library](https://github.com/google/closure-library/blob/master/closure/goog/math/long.js) has a 64-bit long implementation, at least.

Comment: @gsnedders- This is beautiful!  Thanks so much for the link.  I'm out of votes for today but I'll be sure to give you +1 as soon as the next day rolls around.